# tfs2015 sharepoint build definition not producing wsp

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 update 3 to create wsp files from a sharepoint project (standard farm solution with Visual Studio 2013)

I don't have Visual Studio installed on the build server.

the build starts like

> 2016-07-16T02:09:07.5622219Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild
>   version '12.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin'.
>
> 2  2016-07-16T02:09:07.6559950Z All packages listed in packages.config
>   are already installed.
>
> 3  2016-07-16T02:09:07.7653361Z Build started 15/07/2016 23:09:07.

And the msbuild is called:

> /p:IsPackaging=True /p:ReferencePath="C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Sharepoint"

Everything compiles fine, but no wsp files are dropped into bin folder (As supposed to be)

All build log:

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '12.0' from 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin'.  All packages listed in packages.config
>   are already installed.  Build started 15/07/2016 23:09:07.
>         1>Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
>         1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
>             Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
>         1>Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" (1) is building "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\LogIn.csproj" (2) on node 1
>   (Clean target(s)).
>         2>CoreClean:
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\LogIn.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\LogIn.pdb".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\Core.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\bin\Release\Core.pdb".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\obj\Release\LogIn.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\obj\Release\LogIn.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\obj\Release\LogIn.pdb".
>         1>Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" (1) is building "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\Branding.csproj" (3) on
>   node 1 (Clean target(s)).
>         3>CoreClean:
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\obj\Release\Branding.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\obj\Release\Branding.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\obj\Release\Branding.pdb".
>         3>Done Building Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\Branding.csproj" (Clean
>   target(s)).
>
> ```
>   2>Done Building Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent\_work\4\s\LogIn\LogIn.csproj" (Clean target(s)).
>   1>Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent\_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" (1) is building
> ```
>
> "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\SharePoint.ServerWPs.csproj"
>   (6) on node 4 (Clean target(s)).
>         6>CoreClean:
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\SharePoint.ServerWPs.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\SharePoint.ServerWPs.pdb".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Core.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.Office.Server.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\bin\Release\Core.pdb".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\obj\Release\SharePoint.ServerWPs.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\obj\Release\SharePoint.ServerWPs.dll".
>             Deleting file "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\obj\Release\SharePoint.ServerWPs.pdb".
>         6>Done Building Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\SharePoint.ServerWPs\SharePoint.ServerWPs.csproj"
>   (Clean target(s)).
>         1>Done Building Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" (Clean target(s)).  Build
>   succeeded.
>        0 Warning(s)
>        0 Error(s)  Time Elapsed 00:00:00.42  Build started 15/07/2016 23:09:08.
>         1>Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
>         1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
>             Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
>         1>Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" (1) is building "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\Branding.csproj" (2) on
>   node 1 (default targets).
>         2>PrepareForBuild:
>             Creating directory "bin\Release\".
>         1>Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" (1) is building "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Core\Core.csproj" (3) on node 2
>   (default targets).
>         3>RestorePackages:
>             "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Core\packages.config" -source "" 
>   -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\ "
>             Restoring NuGet packages...
>             To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager
>   node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
>             All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
>         2>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
>           Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input
>   files.
>           CoreCompile:
>             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4
>   /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll" /reference:"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /keyfile:key.snk /optimize+
>   /out:obj\Release\Branding.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library
>   /utf8output Features\Branding.Feature\Branding.EventReceiver.cs
>   Helpers\ModuleUpdating.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   "C:\Users\tfsadmin\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>         1>Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" (1) is building "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Structure\Structure.csproj" (5)
>   on node 3 (default targets).
>         5>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
>           Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input
>   files.
>           CoreCompile:
>             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4
>   /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll" /reference:"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /keyfile:key.snk /optimize+
>   /out:obj\Release\Structure.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library
>   /utf8output Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   "C:\Users\tfsadmin\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>           _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll"
>   to "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll".
>         3>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
>           Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input
>   files.
>           CoreCompile:
>             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4
>   /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /reference:C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
>   /reference:C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll" /reference:"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /keyfile:key.snk /optimize+
>   /out:obj\Release\Core.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library
>   /utf8output Configurations\DnnLogin\Constants.cs
>   Configurations\News\NewsFieldID.cs
>   ExtensionMethods\Exceptions\EditorPartException.cs
>   ExtensionMethods\SPExtensions\SPDisposerObj.cs
>   ExtensionMethods\SPExtensions\SPSiteExtensions.cs
>   ExtensionMethods\SPExtensions\SPWebExtensions.cs
>   Helpers\DatabaseHelper.cs Helpers\HtmlHelper.cs Helpers\Log.cs
>   Logging.cs Modes\EnumModeTypes.cs Modes\IModeElement.cs
>   MVP\BaseControls\BaseWebPartControl.cs MVP\Helpers\EditorPartHelper.cs
>   MVP\Helpers\Helpers.cs MVP\Helpers\SPTreePicker.cs
>   MVP\Model\DNNUser.cs MVP\Model\ListItem.cs
>   MVP\Presenter\BasePresenter.cs MVP\Presenter\IPresenter.cs
>   MVP\View\IView.cs
>   "C:\Users\tfsadmin\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>         5>_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll".
>           CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
>             Copying file from "obj\Release\Structure.dll" to "bin\Release\Structure.dll".
>             Structure -> C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Structure\bin\Release\Structure.dll
>             Copying file from "obj\Release\Structure.pdb" to "bin\Release\Structure.pdb".
>         5>Done Building Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Structure\Structure.csproj" (default
>   targets).
>         2>_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll"
>   to "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll".
>         3>_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
>             Copying file from "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll"
>   to "bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll".
>         2>_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll".
>           CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
>             Copying file from "obj\Release\Branding.dll" to "bin\Release\Branding.dll".
>             Branding -> C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\bin\Release\Branding.dll
>             Copying file from "obj\Release\Branding.pdb" to "bin\Release\Branding.pdb".
>         2>Done Building Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\Branding.csproj" (default
>   targets).
>         3>_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll"
>   to "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Sharepoint\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll".
>             Copying file from "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.xml" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.xml".
>             Copying file from "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.xml"
>   to "bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.xml".
>           _CopyAppConfigFile:
>             Copying file from "App.config" to "bin\Release\Core.dll.config".
>           CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
>             Copying file from "obj\Release\Core.dll" to "bin\Release\Core.dll".
>             Core -> C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Core\bin\Release\Core.dll
>             Copying file from "obj\Release\Core.pdb" to "bin\Release\Core.pdb".
>         3>Done Building Project "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Core\Core.csproj" (default targets).
>         Build succeeded.
>           "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>           "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\Branding.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
>           (CoreCompile target) -> 
>             Helpers\ModuleUpdating.cs(75,44): warning CS0618: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus' is obsolete:
>   'SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus is obsolete. Use SPFile.SPCheckOutType
>   instead.' [C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\Branding.csproj]
>             Helpers\ModuleUpdating.cs(75,21): warning CS0618: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.CheckOutStatus' is obsolete:
>   'SPFile.CheckOutStatus is obsolete. Use SPFile.CheckOutType instead.'
>   [C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Branding\Branding.csproj]
>           "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\Sharepoint.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>           "C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\LogIn.csproj" (default target) (7) ->
>             Layouts\LogIn.aspx.cs(24,31): warning CS0114: 'LogIn.Layouts.LogIn.IisSettings' hides inherited member
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.IdentityModelSignInPageBase.IisSettings'.
>   To make the current member override that implementation, add the
>   override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
>   [C:\TfsAgts\Agent_work\4\s\LogIn\LogIn.csproj]
>        3 Warning(s)
>        0 Error(s)  Time Elapsed 00:00:05.53

In another machine with visual studio 2015 and tfs2015sp3 does generate the wsp file. But don't know that i am doing wrong. The solution does compile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio on your build server. Moreover, just make sure your build server environment are the same with your local environment.